# Crystal Reports Conditional Details Section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that joins multiple tables. One possibility for this join is that no rows are returned under part of the selections criteria. Sort of.

I have 3 groups: Movie Rental Place, Type of Movie, Rented / Not Rented / No Interest to Rent.

So an example could be:

1. Blockbuster | Comedy | Rented: List rented movies.
2. Blockbuster | Comedy | Not Rented: List movies not rented.
3. Blockbuster | Comedy | No Interest to Rent: List movies not interested in renting.

Now, I do not want to suppress a section if it is empty, I want to print something else in the Details section of CR. Is there a way to do this?

I am using CR 11.5.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the 'Sort of.' comment again in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, when I was attempting to create a custom formula for the Details section, I was testing on NULL values, when the report was setup to give default values for NULL values. Once I removed that, things worked as intended.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Section Expert and check the "Suppress blank section" option. Add a new section below it (for the static message) and add a suppress formula to that section that uses some isnull check on whichever column indicates "no data".

Comment: I said I do not want to suppress blank sections. I want to print something else if the section is blank or the returned rows if not.

Comment: @Shawn, dotjoe is right. It will suppress the blank section and create a new one which will hold your 'something else'.  And it helps to make sure your tables are right joined.